# Illegal element error in haml markup

Tags: html, templates, haml

I have a section of haml markup that I have within a code pen. I keep getting this error and don't know what I should change.

The error's message is: "Illegal element: classes and ids must have values."

```
.hover_box
  %header.hidden

%section.center-column.center-column-title_block.container
  %h1.address_box-title submit your doggo
  %h3.metadata.author by john kazzatspy
  %h4.metadata.date-published april 09

.carousel.ui.container.cards.small
  .card.
    .image
      %img(src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50")
    .content
      .description fdjsnajfdnsjk fjsanskjfn

%section.center-column.center-column-content
  %textarea.text_input.toSubmit
  %button.ui.button.primary kjkljklj
  .content-container
    %p.content This is a slice of text that I'm serving up to you as a placeholder for all the fabulous content that will be putting in here later.
  %p 
  %p
  %p
  %p

.card-gallery 
%footer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is coming from line 10 in your file:

```
.card.
```

The final `.` is causing Haml to look for another class for this element, but there is none.

You probably just need to delete that `.`:

```
.card
```